# Update ActiveDataItem of XamDataGrid on adding new record

Tags: wpf, mvvm, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am using WPF with MVVM architecture, The problem I am facing is when I add a new record to the grid and press enter, the record is not set as the active record.
Its only when I click on some other record and then again on the new record that it gets updated.

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid  Name="xamDataGrid1" Width="700" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ActiveDataItem="{Binding Listener,Mode=TwoWay}"  DataSource="{Binding GridData.Tables[0].DefaultView}" Padding="50">
```

Is there a way by which I can set the newly added record to the activedataitem property so that It can make a call to the listener in the view model?
I have to insert the new record in the database from the view model.

Comment: What type of collection are you bound to?  Can you use a CollectionChanged event in the ViewModel for when the item is added to the collection?

Answer (score -1):

First make a collection for the `DataSource` and bind it. Next bind the `ActiveDataItem`. In the collection, add the new element. After that you can give `ActiveDataItem` the last element from the collection.

Comment: This is clearly not the answer.... The OP clearly already has a datasoure set. The problem is that when you are adding a row the bound Active data item is null.